# Views 6.x-2.11 problem

Tags: view

I have Views 6.x-2.11 installed as well as image attach module on my system. I'm having a hard time making Views to display multiple images attached to a node. It just shows one image only and that's it. First I thought, slideshow module is at fault and, I removed it and use unformatted style setting instead to make sure if that's the case. To my surprise, it isn't and, even with that setting Views wouldn't show several images of a node. I've searched through web and play around with other settings as well but to no avail. I'm at my wits end and suspect that it is a bug. Anyone here have the same problem? I appreciate much input any help from you guys.

Drupal 6.x